# React Route running into an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, session-storage

I humbly need your help in debugging an infinite react router bug in my code.
My website uses sessionStorage when saving registration details locally before uploading them at the end of the registration process.

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem("agreement", "true");
window.sessionStorage.setItem("token", "token");
window.sessionStorage.setItem("email", "email");
window.sessionStorage.setItem("country_code", "44");
window.sessionStorage.setItem("firstName", "First name");
window.sessionStorage.setItem("lastName", "Last name");
window.sessionStorage.setItem("userPhone", "XXXXXXXXX");
window.sessionStorage.setItem("verified", "true");
```

**EDIT**
The problem occurs between the `/location` and `/setup` route. It's been working fine for the other routes so I don't understand why it's not working

`/location`

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
/* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */
const LocationKYC = ({appLink, loader}) => {

  let [error, setError] = useState(null);
  let [homeAddress, setHomeAddress] = useState("");
  let [workAddress, setWorkAddress] = useState("");
  let [stateRegion, setStateRegion] = useState("");
  let [city, setCity] = useState("");
  let [loading, setLoader] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(window.sessionStorage.getItem("agreement") === "true" &&
      window.sessionStorage.getItem("token") !== null &&
      window.sessionStorage.getItem("email") !== null &&
      window.sessionStorage.getItem("country_code") !== null &&
      window.sessionStorage.getItem("firstName") !== null &&
      window.sessionStorage.getItem("lastName") !== null &&
      window.sessionStorage.getItem("userPhone") !== null &&
      window.sessionStorage.getItem("stateRegion") !== null &&
      window.sessionStorage.getItem("homeAddress") !== null &&
      window.sessionStorage.getItem("userCity") !== null &&
      window.sessionStorage.getItem("verified") !== null) {
        console.log("Redirecting ... 1");
        window.location.href=appLink.register_step_5_account;
        return;
    }

    if(window.sessionStorage.getItem("agreement") === null ||
      window.sessionStorage.getItem("token") === null ||
      window.sessionStorage.getItem("verified") === null ||
      window.sessionStorage.getItem("country_code") === null ||
      window.sessionStorage.getItem("firstName") === null ||
      window.sessionStorage.getItem("lastName") === null ||
      window.sessionStorage.getItem("userPhone") === null ||
      window.sessionStorage.getItem("email") === null) {
        window.sessionStorage.clear();
        console.log("Redirecting ... 2");
        window.location.href=appLink.register_user_agreement;
        return;
    }

    console.log("Redirecting ... 3");
  }, []);

  const updateKYC = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoader(true);

    if(homeAddress.length < 3) {
      setLoader(false);
      setError("Home address is not valid");
      return;
    }

    if(city.length < 2) {
      setLoader(false);
      setError("Phone number is not valid");
      return;
    }

    if(stateRegion.length < 2) {
      setLoader(false);
      setError("Phone number is not valid");
      return;
    }
    
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("stateRegion", stateRegion);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("userCity", city);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("homeAddress", homeAddress);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("workAddress", workAddress);

    window.location.href=appLink.register_step_5_account;
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>

  {
    !loading ? (
      <form method="POST" onSubmit={updateKYC}>
        <div className="row">

          {
            error !== null && (
              <div className="col-12 mt-2 mb-2 text-center">
                <div className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                  {error}
                </div>
              </div>
            )
          }

          <div className="col-12 mb-2 mt-2">
            <div className="form-group mb-2">

                <label htmlFor="">
                  Home Address ( Address Line 1 )
                </label>

                <input className="form-control" type="text" onChange={(e) => setHomeAddress(e.target.value)} placeholder="Home Address" required={true}/>

              </div>
          </div>

          <div className="col-12 mb-2 mt-2">
            <div className="form-group mb-2">

                <label htmlFor="">
                  Work Address ( Address Line 2 )
                </label>

                <input className="form-control" type="text" onChange={(e) => setWorkAddress(e.target.value)} placeholder="Optional" />

              </div>
          </div>

          <div className="col-12 mb-2">
            <div className="form-group mb-2">

                <label htmlFor="">
                  State / Region
                </label>

                <input className="form-control" type="text" onChange={(e) => setStateRegion(e.target.value)} placeholder="Name of Country State / Region" required={true}/>

              </div>
          </div>

          <div className="col-12 mb-2">
            <div className="form-group mb-2">

                <label htmlFor="">
                  City / Town
                </label>

                <input className="form-control" type="text" onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)} placeholder="Name of City within State / Region" required={true}/>

              </div>
          </div>

          <div className="col-12 mb-2">

              <button className="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="submit">
                Proceed <i className="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i>
              </button>

          </div>

        </div>

      </form>
    ) : (
      <div className="col-12 mt-5 text-center">
        <img src={loader} width="70" height="70" alt="Loading"/>
      </div>
    )
  }

    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default LocationKYC;
```

`/setup`

```
 import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
/* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */

const UserAccount = ({appLink, loader}) => {

  let [error, setError] = useState(null);
  let [loading, setLoader] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {

    console.log("Set up running");
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>

      {
        !loading ? (
          <form method="POST">
            <div className="row">
            {
                error !== null && (
                  <div className="col-12 mt-2 mb-2 text-center">
                    <div className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                      {error}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                )
              }
              <div className="col-12 mb-2">
                <div className="form-group mb-2">

                    <label htmlFor="">
                      Username
                    </label>

                    <input className="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username" />

                  </div>
              </div>

              <div className="col-12 mb-2">
                <div className="form-group mb-2">

                    <label htmlFor="">
                      Password
                    </label>

                    <input className="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Password" />

                  </div>
              </div>

              <div className="col-12 mb-2">

                  <button className="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="button" >Complete Registration
                  <i className="ml-2 fa fa-check"></i></button>

              </div>

            </div>
        </form>
        ) : (
          <div className="col-12 mt-5 text-center">
            <img src={loader} width="70" height="70" alt="Loading"/>
          </div>
        )
      }
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default UserAccount;
```

This is my application route paths and route code
`app_links.jsx`

```
export default (
   {
    appRoot : "/",
    signIn : "/signIn",
    register_user_agreement: "/agreement",
    register_step_1_create: "/create",
    register_step_2_verify: "/verify",
    register_step_3_info: "/personal",
    register_step_4_location: "/location",
    register_step_5_account: "/setup",
    register_verify_email: "http://localhost:8080/misc/verify_email",
    register_verify_code: "http://localhost:8080/misc/verify_code",
    getCountries: "http://localhost:8080/misc/countries",
  }
);
```

Route Browser
`index.js`

```
<React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <Switch>
      <Route exact path={appLinks.default.appRoot} component={App} />
      <Route exact path={appLinks.default.register_user_agreement} component={RenderAgreementPage} />
      <Route exact path={appLinks.default.register_step_1_create} component={RenderRegisterPage} />
      <Route exact path={appLinks.default.register_step_2_verify} component={RenderVerificationPage} />
      <Route exact path={appLinks.default.register_step_3_info} component={RenderPersonalInfo} />
      <Route exact path={appLinks.default.register_step_4_gh_location} component={RenderLocationInfo} />
      <Route exact path={appLinks.default.signIn} component={RenderUserSignIn} />
      <Route exact path={appLinks.default.register_step_5_account} component={RenderAccountConfiguraton} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please do try to update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example of the component you suspect is causing issue.

Comment: Added please @Reese

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code took more than 1 hr to debug, also nearly broke my browser :D . You made a typo in your code.

The route you mentioned for Location is

```
<Route exact path={appLinks.default.register_step_4_gh_location} component={RenderLocationInfo} />
```

You added an extra ***gh*** in the link.

I removed and tried

```
    <Route exact path={appLinks.default.register_step_4_location} component={RenderLocationInfo} />
```

This worked fine later. I was debugging all registration codes and could not find any errors. Finally, I checked your appLinks one by one and found the typo in index.js routes.

Due to the typo, the Route path is empty and when the app was searching for a matching route, as this route comes before setup, it was continuously falling here.